# What does the r in re sub do?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
s = "1234Bananas"
s = re.sub(r"\d", "", s)
```

I know this will select the digits `1234`, but what does the lowercase `r` stands for and do?

```
re.sub(**r**"\d", "", s)
```

Comment: It is used for **raw string** so that you don't need to do double escaping.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me